An error occurred while reading the key ring in China cloud
We have a service deployed with this code:
services.AddDataProtection(opt =>
    opt.ApplicationDiscriminator = configurationOptions.Authentication.AzureAd.ClientId)
        .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(
            new Uri(storageAccountEndpointUri), new DefaultAzureCredential())
        .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(
            new Uri(configurationOptions.StorageAccountKeyVaultProtectKeyIdentifier),
            new DefaultAzureCredential());

However, the service is not loading and the logs have this error:
"An error occurred while reading the key ring" and it seems to be from "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider"
This is the only error that is there and I am unable to understand the source of this error. Any pointers here would be greatly appreciated!

Is it working in local environment?

Have you got all permissions to access the keys?

Is the key Vault is created with Azure role based or vault policy based?

Could you please tell me where you host this application? Inside the Azure service or local server?

@Venkatesan yes it works in local environment and in production clouds. Permissions are also same as what is in other clouds. The same template is deployed everywhere. Key vault is role based.

@BrandoZhang The application is on service fabric

@AarthiVishwanathan Could you please tell which role is assigned to user?

The issue is fixed now, thanks!

It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community

The error message was thrown due to an incorrect domain name suffix in the China cloud configuration file for the storage account that was getting created as part of the deployment. Once the domain name suffix was updated in the config, it started to work.
